# Do Germans use “Okay” or “OK” to agree to a request or confirm that they’ve understood?

Tags: word-usage

For example, in English:

> P1: Can you keep this suitcase for me for an hour?
>   P2: Okay.

Or in the case of confirmation of information processed by the receiving person of the dialogue:

> P1: I need the book now.
>   P2: Okay.

Do Germans use *Okay* or *OK* or what is the equivalent in those scenarios?

And considering the *K* in German sounds different, if *OK* is used, then how is it pronounced? Oh-kah? Also, if it is used at all, then where is the appropriate setting to use it (colloquially, professionally, etc.)?

Answer (score 22):

Yes, German uses *Ok,* too, and the usage is very similar to its English counterpart — to the point where I wouldn’t be able to tell you any diverging usage off the top of my head. It is usually spelt out *okay.*

The pronunciation is *not,* however, /o:ka:/ as might have been expected from the pronunciation of the letters *O* and *K*. Two pronunciations exist and I would be hesitant to say either is superiour over the other:

- /o:kɛɪ/ — basically pronouncing the *K* in an English way
- /o:ke:/ — which might lead to an alternate spelling *oke(e).*

I wouldn’t use *okay* in very formal settings, in which I would consider it nigh unacceptable. However, in practically all other contexts — colloquial, casual professional, etc — I would consider it fine.

Comment: The formal settings must indeed be _very_ formal for _okay_ not being acceptable. Like an appointment with The Queen or The Pope or similar unique persons and/or circumstances. And Darth Vader wouldn't accept it either. :-)

Comment: Also encountered, semi-ironic /o:kaɪ̯/ and shortened /kɛɪ/ or /ke:/ ⟨k⟩, even sometimes reduplicated as /ke'ke:/. Almost equivalent gestures are  and , whereas  is not understood. It can be inflected as an adjective informally, _okaye/-r/-s/-n/-m_.

Comment: Like in English, it all depends on _how_ it is said. Like in English, it doesn't _necessarily_ mean yes, depending on how it was said.

Comment: Do you have sources for "It is usually spelt out _okay_"? In my personal experience it is almost exclusively spelt "OK" - for which I, sadly, do not have a source...

Comment: Just a short note, sometimes the o is dropped and simply "k" ("kay") is said. This is especially popular with youths. In written texts (SMS, WhatApp), sometimes "kk" is used instead of "ok" or "k".

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek No sources; it’s just my personal experience.

Comment: Same people say _oki_ or _okidoki_

Comment: Never saw the alternate spelling _oke(e)_ -- appears to be "original research". Also: disagree about the setting, just like PerlDuck.

Comment: @Crissov: I'd be careful with the second gesture (index finger and thumb together to form an *O*); here in Germany, that can also mean "a..hole".

Comment: It should be noted that there are a few strange people in German speaking countries who consider the word "OK" rude and respectless. Anyway, it's usually safe to use.

Comment: Und mein Physiklehrer sagte "Ohkai", weil er das in Südengland so gehört hatte.

Comment: The issue with OK in formal settings is simply that it's very imprecise. It can mean anything between "that's the best thing ever" and "whatever you say...". Also, it's a filler word.

Answer (score 8):

We (Germans) use and pronounce it the same way as English speakers do it. But just like in English we also have different terms to express agreement:

- sicher — sure
- natürlich/klar — of course

A simple *Ja* — *Yes* is also common.

Comment: *Jawohl/Jawoll* is also used sometimes, though clicking your heels while saying it is mostly frowned upon nowadays ;-)

Comment: Makes me wonder, is the _na_ in _na sicher_, _na klar_ and _na ja_ related to _natürlich_?

Comment: When would you use *genau*? Similar as "OK"?

Comment: Where does "stimmt" fit into the picture?

Comment: @Crissov, *na* is not related to *natürlich*, cf. *na denn?* but *natürlich denn?* is complete gibberish; It is a flavoring [particle](http://germanforenglishspeakers.com/other/modal-particles/). The comparison is very vague, but consider it roughly similar to how English speakers use *well* (which can also be a particle): *Well, yes!* / *Well, sure.* / *Well, what [do you mean]?*

Comment: @microtherion, I've never heard a German native speaker use *jawohl* in a way which is not sarcastic/ironic, so I'd be careful about using that word... but then, I only very rarely interact with Germanophones over the age of 40, so my view may be skewed.

Comment: I've heard at least one waiter use *jawohl* (in BW).  Pretty sure it wasn't sarcastic ... but I too would avoid using it myself (in case people thought I was taking the piss).

Comment: My teachers would often say "Alles klar?" with the expected response being either "Alles klar." or "OK" or "klar" if things were going well.  Is that a habit that a german trying to teach english pupils has developed or is it a common phrase in some regions of Germany too?  I think once of the assistants did use to use "OK?" for a similar purpose too and it almost fits your answer.

Comment: @BruceWayne "genau" in German is "exactly" in English. It can also be an affirmative answer like in "You don't eat fish?" — "Exactly." ("Du isst keinen Fisch?" — "Genau."). We wouldn't say "OK" here but merely "Ja/Genau/Richtig/Stimmt" ("Yes/Exactly/Right/True"). It's just like in English.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 "stimmt" is like "true" or "right" and can be used as in my preceeding comment. Actually it boils down to _"You can use OK in German whenever you can use it in English"_.

Comment: @PerlDuck, it's interesting that you don't include "OK" in the list "Ja/Genau/Richtig/Stimmt". English speakers certainly *would* include it, ie "Yes/Exactly/Right/True/OK".

Comment: @Crissov as errantlinguist said, it is a particle, an interjection. Funnily enough you could hear greetings being done exclusively with that particle: "1: na? 2: na" (where normally the "a" in "na" is elongated so that it is like "naah"). This exchange would mean "1: hi, how are you? 2: hi, fine thanks" Note that I've heard this in Berlin, so it might be dialectal/local usage.

Comment: @errantlinguist: "Jawohl" (instead of just "ja") can make it *clearer* you have heard, and understood. ("Ja" is "quieter", and more easily overheard.) Especially in noisy environments, or over distances. That is the reason why the German army insists on "jawohl" instead of "ja" to confirm an order. While certainly... strange... in a casual conversation at the dinner table, "jawohl" is not that uncommon where you have to shout your answer. The colloquial "jau" serves a similar purpose in northern Germany, as does lengthening the "ja" ("ja-ha!"). (Consider "nine" / "niner".)

Comment: @Roamer-1888, as an American English native, *OK* is **not** an intelligible response to *Do you not eat fish?*...

Comment: @DevSolar, on second thought, I have heard people in service situations say something like "Ja*wohl*!" and, while not exactly sarcastic, it came off to me (albeit as a non-native speaker) as someone trying to consciously act "extra" chipper in a humorous fashion (i.e. "Yes, I'm an absolute schnitzel-and-beer-serving machine!"). Still, it is definitely more audible.

Comment: @errantlinguist, my point wasn't well considered. I totally agree that "OK" makes little sense, maybe none, as a response to "you don't eat fish?", and not a commonly appropriate response to questions in general. I think I was seduced by "you don't eat fish?" being a statement used as an interrogative, a form that I seldom if ever use. On reflection, what I should have said is that "OK" can be added to the list "Yes/Exactly/Right/True" as a candidate affirmative or ambiguous response to a *statement*.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter what you say, it's almost the same. *Okay* can sometimes be taken sarcastic but not for foreigner. So don't worry.
The pronunciation for *OK* is "Oh keh", so just the letters; and for *okay* it is the English *okay*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: ok; klar; Alles klar; kein Problem; kein Thema (like "kein Problem, but more colloquial) ^^

Answer (score 0):

I have been in Germany for 5 months now(Frankfurt and Berlin). I have noticed that though they understand Okay, the usage is very minimal. Most often I use Okay as a normal English speaker, but it sounds a bit out of place in Germany when I speak in German.

For the first scenario, the most probable response would be

> P1: Can you keep this suitcase for me for an hour?
>
> P2: Ja, gerne.

And for the second scenario, it would be "Okay" and then something like "I will give it" etc.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of your examples would be considered as a bit "cold" way to answer.
You would usually answer in a more ensuring way like "yes, of course".

So if you ask a German "how do you like it?" and he or she replies "it's ok" its not good but also not too bad.

A more common way to to use it in German is in questions, i.e.: 
"Is it ok if I put my suitcase over here?" – "Yeah, sure!"

The correct form to use it in German is "ok" or "OK".
The expression is actually German. It's an acronym for "ohne Korrektur" (no corrections). It was an office terminology for business people to sign the letters their secretaries wrote. So if the letter was fine, you would say: It is "ok" (without corrections) and therefore can be sent out.

That's why its considered as a more technically term.

Comment: The certain etymology of OK is unknown. "ohne Korrektur" is one of many proposed theories: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_proposed_etymologies_of_OK

Comment: I don’t trust that etymology. If it is true, why is *okay* considered as coming from English? Why does it end up getting pronounced *okee* rather than *okah?*